# ExtJS 3 Make south panel go in between east and west panels

Tags: layout, extjs, panel

I was hoping it is possible to make a south panel (in a border layout Viewport), go in between the east and west panels.

It is demonstrated in [this](http://www.sencha.com/learn/ext-js-4-panel-docked-items/) video, however weight is a ExtJS 4 configuration.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this in ExtJS 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You nest configs. Your outer config defines east, west, and center, and you center has a center and a south. This puts 'south' between east and west, rather than spanning all three.